# Unable to create mongotemplate in spring

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mvc

Error:

> 19-Feb-2016 00:00:16.731 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log StandardWrapper.Throwable
>    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate com.test.app.service.PersonService.mongoTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionServiceFactory.createDefaultConversionService()Lorg/springframework/core/convert/support/GenericConversionService;

```html
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo" 
 xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.2.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.app" />
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
 <bean
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix">
   <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
  </property>
  <property name="suffix">
   <value>.jsp</value>
  </property>
 </bean>
<!-- Factory bean that creates the Mongo instance -->
  <bean id="mongo" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoFactoryBean">
  <property name="host" value="localhost" />
 </bean>
 
 
 <!-- MongoTemplate for connecting and querying the documents in the database -->
 <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
  <constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongo" />
  <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="test" />
 </bean>

 <!-- Use this post processor to translate any MongoExceptions thrown in @Repository annotated classes -->
 <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />
 
 <bean id="personController" class="com.test.app.controller.PersonController" />
    <bean id="personService" class="com.test.app.service.PersonService" />
    <bean id="person" class="com.test.app.model.Person" />
 
 
</beans>
```

I am seeing many posts regarding this error , but no answers to fix this.

Answer (score 5):

The version of spring-core need match the version of spring-data.
Below is my part pom.xml:

```
  <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
       <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Spring data mongodb -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.2.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
```

It's fixed.

Comment: This seemed to work for me - having the version match seems stupid but it works. Frustrating - but thanks!

Comment: My `spring-core` version is `5.1.2.RELEASE` and that of `spring-data-mongodb` is `2.1.2.RELEASE`, I am still getting same error. Help would be appreciated. TIA.

Answer (score 2):

It's almost the same thing only annotation driven. In the `Supplier` I'm just casting `mongoTemplate` (You may not want that). So If you use the spring config everything should work fine.

Regarding your version in XML try creating the `mongo factory` from `SimpleMongoDbFactory` with a `MongoClient` and the database name, Then just give your `MongoTemplate` bean your factory, and that's it.

Spring Config:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringConfig {

    @Bean
    public MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() throws UnknownHostException{
        return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new MongoClient(),"games");
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws UnknownHostException{
        MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());      
        return mongoTemplate;
    }

}
```

After that I created a `supplier` (`Google Guava` in this case) which may not be needed in your case

```
public class MongoOperationSupplier implements Supplier<MongoOperations>{
    @Override
    public MongoOperations get() {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringConfig.class);
        MongoOperations mongoOperation = (MongoOperations) ctx.getBean("mongoTemplate");
        return mongoOperation;
    }
}
```

An annotated class:

```
@Document(collection="game_suspicious_event")
public class SuspiciousEvent {
    @Id
    private String id;

    private String apiKey;
    private String userUniqueId;
    private Date date;
    private String ip;
    private String additionalInformation;

    public SuspiciousEvent(){}

    public SuspiciousEvent(String apiKey,String userUniqueId,Date date, String ip, String additionalInformation){
        this.apiKey=apiKey;
        this.userUniqueId=userUniqueId;
        this.date=date;
        this.ip=ip;
        this.additionalInformation=additionalInformation;
    }

    public String getApiKey() {
        return apiKey;  
    }
}
```

Then to use:

```
final MongoOperations mo = new MongoOperationSupplier().get();
mo.save(new SuspiciousEvent(......));
```

Hope it helps.